# pip install opencv-python gives error on Raspbian

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, pip, opencv

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with Raspbian installed.

When I run `pip install opencv-python` I get the following message:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting opencv-python
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from version: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python
```

I've tried `pip install opencv-contrib-python`, `python3 -m pip install opencv-python` and that gives me the same error.

And `pip install --upgrade pip` before trying to install opencv, but it says I already have the latest version.

What I have:

```
 $ python --version
Python 2.7.13

 $ python3 --version
Python 3.6.3

 $ pip --version
pip 19.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Comment: see https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/102

Comment: There are no prebuilt wheels of `opencv-python` for Python 3.6 on ARM platforms yet and it looks like Python 3.6 will be skipped completely as Raspbian Buster will be shipped with Python 3.7. Downgrade `python3` to Python 3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it using sudo apt-get install python-opencv

Comment: This installs a very old version, but at the moment there seems to be no other option other than compiling from source. More info at https://github.com/piwheels/packages/issues/28